# How change the source ip address udp package to a fake ip in golang?

Tags: go, udp

I need recive udp package and send their to broadcast address other interface.

I wrote udp forward server. Its work!
How change the source udp address new packages to src address income package?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func CheckError(err error) {
    if err  != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: " , err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}

func main() {
    ServerAddr,err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4",":10001")
    CheckError(err)

    LocalAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "192.168.164.83:10001")
    CheckError(err)

    RemoteAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "192.168.164.255:10002")
    CheckError(err)

    Conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp4", LocalAddr, RemoteAddr)
    CheckError(err)

    defer Conn.Close()

    ServerConn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", ServerAddr)
    CheckError(err)
    defer ServerConn.Close()

    buf := make([]byte, 2048)

    for {
        n,addr,err := ServerConn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
        fmt.Println("Received ",n , "bytes from ",addr)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error-recive: ",err)
        } else {
            go Conn.Write(buf[0:n])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The source IP is set by the OS network stack, nothing in your code here is going to effect that. You have to create a raw packet yourself: https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket#hdr-Creating_Packet_Data